# How do I configure a per-test-method instantiation of a SpringBoot with Junit?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a unit test that instantiates the application once for JUnit test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "server.port=9000",
        classes = Application.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class TodoWebDriverTest {
  // many test methods
}
```

But I wish to tear down and instantiate the application (socket listener 'n' all) **per test method**. I am relying on a couple of annotations presently (see above) but would happily abandon them for a reliable pure-Java launch/start capability:

```
app = SpringSomething.prepare(Appication.class, other params);
app.start();
waitForProofOfBeingStarted(app);
```

Here, I forked someone else's application - https://github.com/paul-hammant/todo-backend-spring4-java8 - and added wire-mocking (without a service virtualization framework) and three WebDriver tests. All in all the build is about 30 seconds. **This shows a once-per-test-class app setup**, and is towards a larger solution that will show multiple Junit testing phases in a pipeline, but I need to flip it to **once-per-test-method app setup**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [`@DirtiesContext` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#__dirtiescontext)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = "server.port=9000",
        classes = Application.class,
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class TodoWebDriverTest {
  // many test methods
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder too, if there is a way of overriding the SpringBoot boot as I do for https://github.com/paul-hammant/todobackend-jooby (granted Jooby isn't SpringBoot)